# Cannot download file response from api when call api with axios

Tags: node.js

Previously, the form had an action to api direct and api will response the file back to download

```
<form action="http://158.108.168.11:9997/upload"  method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Now, the form had an action to /upload which call api via axios The problem is when i call to api It doesn't have response a file to download

```
<form action="/upload"  method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

```
router.post("/upload", multer.single('file'), async(req, res) => {
     const fileRecievedFromClient = req.file; 
    let form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', fileRecievedFromClient.buffer, fileRecievedFromClient.originalname);
    form.append('name', req.body.name);



    await axios.post('http://158.108.168.11:9997/upload', form, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}`,
                'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;'

            }
        })
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code in the body of the question instead of sharing an image

Comment: @DashiellRoseBark-Huss okay I will post the code in the body

Comment: can you make sure you're using `app.use(express.urlencode({ extended: false }))` and wrap the axios call with a try so you can see the error it outputs, might have some clue on what you're doing wrong

Comment: sure i use it but it didn't send any error.  API can get the form Data sent and processed everything, but unable to receive response file download from API since call API with axios. But direct API calls action in form it able to receive response file download from API.

Comment: i think problem with header in axios.